# Facebook - Send friend request to Facebook from an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, mobile-application

I am developing an iOS app that allows users to send friend request to other FB users from the app. I am using FBWebDialogs to send the friend request. The web dialog appears with the option to send the friend request.

I am using this piece of code to open the dialog to send the friend request.

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @“My”AppID, @"app_id",
                                   mUserId, @"id",
                                   nil];


[FBWebDialogs presentDialogModallyWithSession:nil dialog:@"friends" parameters:[params mutableCopy] handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
{
   if (error) {
        // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
        NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (result = FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
            NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
        }
        else
        {
        NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
            if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"])
            {
                // User clicked the Cancel button
                NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
            }
            else
            {
                // User clicked the Send button
                NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
            }

        }
    }
} delegate:self];
```

But, the dialog gives an error "We're working on getting this fixes as soon as we can".

I am not sure if this is a Facebook error or I am sending the 'params' wrong. I would like to get some assistance from anyone to get this thing working.

Your assistance will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you working in sandbox mode of your app ? If so make sure both accounts are added as testing account.

Comment: Yes, I am working in sandbox mode of the app. I tried with both test users account as well as normal FB accounts. Both of them gives the same error.

"We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can"